# What is corresponding to GStack.HostToNetwork() in Indy10

Tags: c++builder, indy, indy10

My Environment:

```
C++ Builder XE4
Indy 10.6.0.4975
```

I am searching information on conversion from host byte order to network byte order.

I found info for Indy 9 using GStack.HostToNetwork(). However, I do not find one for Indy10.

What is corresponding one for Indy10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your information backwards.

There were no `TIdStack::HostToNetwork()` (or `TIdStack::NetworkToHost()`) methods in Indy 9.  They were `TIdStack::WSHToN...()` (and `TIdStack::WSNToH...()`) instead.

`TIdStack::HostToNetwork()` **is** for Indy 10.  There are also `HostToLittleEndian()` (and `LittleEndianToHost()`) functions in `IdGlobal.hpp`.